# jQuery textarea keyUp is breaking all following code

Tags: jquery, textarea, keyup

I feel that I might be overlooking something here. I wan to display the character count of a textarea in a `<span>` element underneath the `<textarea>`. I am using the following jQuery and HTML:

jQuery:

```
$('#ws3 .textarea textarea[name="company-description"]').keyUp(function() {

var charLength = $(this).val().length;

$('span#charCount').html(charLength + ' of 250 characters used');

if($(this).val().length > 250)
$('span#charCount').html('<strong>You may only have up to 250 characters.</strong>');

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ws3" class="ws-section">
<label for="company-description">Describe your company for us</label>
<div class="textarea">
  <textarea id="company-description" name="company-description" class="ws-required"></textarea>
</div>
<span id="charCount">charCount</span>
</div>
```

Also, all jQuery code following this block does not work, almost as if the browser has stopped reading the .js file at this block of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `keyUp` function.. change it to `keyup` and then it should work fine..

```
$('#ws3 .textarea textarea[name="company-description"]').keyup(function() {
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/gJDJJ/)

**Tips:**

1. When there is script error, Javascript compiler will stop executing the following lines below the error line and will continue on to next `js` file or next `<script>` block
2. In future, whenever you have some issue with a script, please look at the console for errors. Below is what I got when I used `keyUp`

> **Error:**  $("#ws3 .textarea textarea[name=\"company-description\"]").keyUp is not a function

Comment: Sometimes, I don't think people realize how good they have it on Stackoverflow. +1.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `keyUp` function in jQuery the function name is [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/csM3L/)

Comment: /me slaps his own head. Thanks Joy!